I need some help to create a logo and to be inverted in css
there is this logo, from Mccan Design enter image description here
and is somehow inverted, and I'm trying to copy the style but I'm new at this and not sure what to do.
I've created the logo in Illustrator and saved it as .svg (not sure if any of the options when saving .svg needs to be changed) and in index.html I'm adding the logo as img (if I add it as svg code it breaks other functionalities):
<div id="logo">
<img class="title my-5" src="image/marketing-logo.svg" alt="Marketing">
</div>

and in css:
.logo  {
    filter: invert(88%) sepia(91%) saturate(1%) hue-rotate(257deg) brightness(107%) contrast(101%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

but it's not working..
Thanks in advance

Try mix-blend-mode: difference.

You are using style with class selector
1.Either change <div id="logo"> to <div class="logo">
or in the style use # (id) selector
#logo  {
    filter: invert(88%) sepia(91%) saturate(1%) hue-rotate(257deg) brightness(107%) contrast(101%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}


changed it but doesn't do anything:
html:



</header>

css:
#logo  {
filter: invert(0.8) sepia(0.9) saturate(0.1) hue-rotate(257deg) brightness(1) contrast(1);
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

I checked your code and found some issues. First, .logo is class name so it will affect to class="logo", not id="logo". Second is, you can't see your svg logo because your filter value is too brightness, it's 107% so it will fully hide svg logo with white color so I changed it to 50%. Or you can change other params of filter.
<html>
    <style>
        .logo  {
            /* You can adjust brightness value if you want */
            filter: invert(88%) sepia(91%) saturate(1%) hue-rotate(257deg) brightness(50%) contrast(101%);
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, 0);
        }
    </style>

    <body>
        <div class="logo">
            <img class="title my-5" src="logo.svg" alt="Marketing">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

It will show like below image.


thank you for the reply, but it still doesn't work. On that website maccann.design, when it has white background it goes black and the other way. but also when it has a red background it goes green, on blue background goes red, on purple goes sepia and so on. that is what i'm trying to achieve and I cannot for the world of me understand whay its not working

Oh, I see what you want. Will give you good answer soon.

sorry to bug you, did you by any chance managed to come up with an answer?

Hi, @Wietenberg, I didn't get correct answer yet but trying to find a good solution now. I will definitely let you know if I find a solution

And our goal is to learn and teach each other I think. If you solve the issue before me, please don't forget to share it with me.
